# SQL Server - query XML node DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:Name in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to query out the contents of both "fields" in DTS:Name="ConnectionString".  (Specifically, the text that begins with "".  There can be multiple - in this example, there's 2.

I can't figure out how to query it.  Between the colon and the dts: dts:, I'm stumped

Any help appreciated.

```
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.Package.2">
  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="SuppressConfigurationWarnings">0</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:ConnectionManager>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:ObjectData>
      <DTS:ConnectionManager>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;Application Name=blah;</DTS:Property>
      </DTS:ConnectionManager>
    </DTS:ObjectData>
  </DTS:ConnectionManager>
  <DTS:ConnectionManager>
    <DTS:ObjectData>
      <DTS:ConnectionManager>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=myserver2;Initial Catalog=mydb2;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;</DTS:Property>
      </DTS:ConnectionManager>
    </DTS:ObjectData>
  </DTS:ConnectionManager>
</DTS:Executable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear, but I'm assuming you want the connection strings themselves. So, let's imagine the document is in an `XML` type column called `XmlColumn` that is in a table called `@XmlTable`, then you could do this...

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' as dts) 
SELECT Con.Str.value('.', 'varchar(400)')
FROM @XmlTable
CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('//dts:Property[@dts:Name="ConnectionString"]') as Con(Str)
```

Note, we need to handle the [XML namespace using the `WITH` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the semi-colon at the start is not a mistake. Then we pass an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression to the [`nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method of the `xml` type, in order to retrieve the items you require.

See it in action [here at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14717).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, and that's exactly what it does - THANKS!  I knew about the Namespace, but never would have come up with that.

Comment: No probs. Neither would I without the info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx). Should have also included that link in the original answer. Added it now.